# Sudden crash when click on CheckBoxes (NPE exception)

Tags: android, string, checkbox, onclick, append

when I try to run this code, the app crashed from the start.

I have two checkboxes and onclick I am appending a given value to a String.
Later on I am sharing this string through a SHARE Intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
String result ="";
CheckBox checkBox1;
CheckBox checkBox2;
View.OnClickListener checkBoxListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final int value1 = 300;
    final double value2 = 3.14;
    final short value3 = 5;
    final char value4 = 'A';
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    // Create StringBuilder and add four values to it.
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


    checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
                builder.append(value1).append("\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(checkBox2.isChecked()){
                builder.append(value2).append("\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    checkBox1.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    checkBox1.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

My layout is rather simple. Only two checkboxes with the right IDs and a button to trigger the share intent. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure why u are onclicklistener your checkbox. See usage example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Comment: you are right Simon! I am too tired and didn't catch the pitfall: I used ImageView earlier on and replacing them with checkboxes I forgot to amend all the due bits.
It should be now working, according to the Google Developr guide, but it still crashes, anyway! :o
Code edited

Comment: Can you add to your question the layout xml and the crash log?

Comment: Hi Fer it's solved now thanks :)